# Как сделать прозрачный фон в приложении?

Tags: android, background

Как сделать чтобы фон был прозрачным (было видно обои на телефоне), как в kate mobile?
[image: Kate]

Answer (score 6):

Translucent тема приложения
Но вообще лучше получить картинку фона рабочего стола и поставить ее фоном активити

Answer (score 4):

Я в манифесте реализовал такой стиль:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>

</style>
```